# Magento 2 Index Contoller on Custom Module

Tags: magento2, product, orders, email, magento2.2.4

I have added the custom order form on product page. When cutomer enters the details and submit the form then the Order will be created in backend and also confirmation email will send to customer immediately.

For this I have created custom module and added the Index controller to **create order and send email** as well. But its not working and gives the following message

```
Fatal error: Class Company\Modulename\Controller\Index\Index contains 1 abstract method and must therefore be declared abstract or implement the remaining methods (Magento\Framework\App\ActionInterface::execute)
```

Here is my **Index.php** file added in Custom module's Controller.

```
<?php
namespace Company\Modulename\Controller\Index;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;

class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{

protected $_storeManager;

protected $_product;

protected $_formkey;

protected $quote;

protected $quoteManagement;

protected $customerFactory;

protected $customerRepository;

protected $orderService;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context $context,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product,
        \Magento\Framework\Data\Form\FormKey $formkey,
        \Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteFactory $quote,
        \Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteManagement $quoteManagement,
    \Magento\Sales\Model\Service\OrderService $orderService,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerFactory $customerFactory,
        \Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepository,
        \Magento\Quote\Api\CartRepositoryInterface $cartRepositoryInterface,
        \Magento\Quote\Api\CartManagementInterface $cartManagementInterface
    ) {
        $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->_product = $product;
        $this->_formkey = $formkey;
        $this->quote = $quote;
        $this->quoteManagement = $quoteManagement;
    $this->orderService = $orderService;
        $this->customerFactory = $customerFactory;
        $this->customerRepository = $customerRepository;
        $this->cartRepositoryInterface = $cartRepositoryInterface;
        $this->cartManagementInterface = $cartManagementInterface;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

  public function CreateOrder($productData, $userData) {

        try {
            $storeObject = $this->_storeManager->load(1); // Store ID
        }
        catch(Exeception $ex)
        {

        }

        $quote = $this->quote->create()->loadByIdWithoutStore($quoteId);


        $productId = $this->_product->getIdBySku($productData['sku']); // Bundle Product SKU

         $params = array(
            'product' =>  $productId
        );

        $request = new Varien_Object();
        $request->setData($params);

        $_value['Email'] = $userData['email'];
        $_value['First Name'] = $userData['firstname'];
        $_value['Last Name'] = $userData['lastname'];
        $_value['Address'] = $userData['address'];
        $_value['City'] = $userData['city'];
        $_value['Telephone'] = $userData['telephone'];

        // create customer
        $customer = $this->customerFactory;
        $password = 'xxxxxxx';

        $customer->setWebsiteId(1); // Set Website ID
        $customer->loadByEmail($_value['Email']);
        $customer->setWebsiteId(1); // Set Website ID AGAIN!

        if(!$customer->getId()) {
            $customer->setEmail($_value['Email']);
            $customer->setFirstname($_value['First Name']);
            $customer->setLastname($_value['Last Name']);
            $customer->setPassword($password);
            $customer->setMode(Mage_Checkout_Model_Cart_Customer_Api::MODE_REGISTER);
        }
        else
        {
            $customer->setMode(Mage_Checkout_Model_Cart_Customer_Api::MODE_CUSTOMER);
        }

        try {
            $customer->save();
            $customer->setConfirmation(null);
            $customer->save();
        }
        catch (Exception $ex) {
            error_log(var_dump($ex));
        }

        if (! $customer->getId() ){
            return $this;                
        }

        $dataShipping = array(
            'firstname'  => $_value['First Name'],
            'lastname'   => $_value['Last Name'],
            'street'     => $_value['Address'],
            'city'       => $_value['City'],
            'region'     => '',
            'region_id'  => '',
            'country_id' => 'INR', //todo: un-hardcode this.
            'telephone'  => $_value['Telephone'],
        );

        $customerAddress = $this->customerRepository;

        if ($defaultShippingId = $customer->getDefaultShipping()){
             $customerAddress->load($defaultShippingId); 
        } else {   
             $customerAddress
                ->setCustomerId($customer->getId())
                ->setIsDefaultShipping('1')
                ->setSaveInAddressBook('1')
             ;
             $customer->addAddress($customerAddress);
        }            

        try {
            $customerAddress
                ->addData($dataShipping)
                ->save()
            ;           
        } catch(Exception $e){

        }

        $customer->save();

        $product = new Mage_Catalog_Model_Product();
        $product->load($productId);
        $product->setPrice($productData['price']);

        $quote->addProduct($product, $request);
        $quote->setCustomer($customer);
        $quote->assignCustomer($customer);


        $quote->getShippingAddress()->addData($dataShipping)->setShippingMethod('tablerate_bestway');
        $quote->getShippingAddress()->setShippingMethod('tablerate_bestway');
        $quote->getShippingAddress()->setCollectShippingRates(true);
        $quote->getShippingAddress()->collectShippingRates(); 
        $quote->setPayment($quote->getPayment()->setMethod('free'));


        $quote->collectTotals();


        $quote->save();

        $convertQuoteObj = $this->cartManagementInterface;
        $orderObj = $convertQuoteObj->toOrder($quote);

        $orderPaymentObj=$convertQuoteObj->paymentToOrderPayment($quote->getPayment());

        $orderObj->setBillingAddress($convertQuoteObj->addressToOrderAddress($quote->getBillingAddress()));
        $orderObj->setPayment($convertQuoteObj->paymentToOrderPayment($quote->getPayment()));
        $orderObj->setShippingAddress($convertQuoteObj->addressToOrderAddress($quote->getShippingAddress()));


        $qty = $productData['quantity'];

        foreach ($quote->getShippingAddress()->getAllItems() as $item) {
            //@var $item Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Item
            $item->setQty($qty);
            $orderItem = $convertQuoteObj->itemToOrderItem($item);
            if ($item->getParentItem()) {
                $orderItem->setParentItem($orderObj->getItemByQuoteItemId($item->getParentItem()->getId()));
            }
            $orderObj->addItem($orderItem);
        }

          $orderObj->setCustomerNote($productData['customernote']);

          $orderObj->setSubtotal($productData['price']);
          $orderObj->setBaseSubtotal($productData['price']);

          $orderObj->setGrandTotal($productData['price']);
          $orderObj->setBaseGrandTotal($productData['price']);

        $orderObj->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getStoreId());

        $orderObj->setCanShipPartiallyItem(false);

        $totalDue=$orderObj->getTotalDue();

        $orderObj->place(); //calls _placePayment
        $orderObj->save();
        return $orderId=$orderObj->getId();

    }



     public function mailAction()
    {

    $objectManager =  \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();        

    $storeManager = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface');


        if (!$_POST)
        {
            echo "IN Not Post<br>";
            exit;
        }


        function isValidEmail($email){ 
          return filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
        }

        function clean($string) {
           $string = str_replace(' ', '-', $string); // Replaces all spaces with hyphens.
           $string = preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9,.?\-]/', '', $string); // Removes special chars.

           $string = preg_replace('/-+/', '-', $string); // Replaces multiple hyphens with single one.
           $string = str_replace('-', ' ', $string); // Replaces all spaces with hyphens.
           return $string;
        }

        if( !function_exists('apache_request_headers') ) {
            function apache_request_headers() {
              $arh = array();
              $rx_http = '/\AHTTP_/';
              foreach($_SERVER as $key => $val) {
                if( preg_match($rx_http, $key) ) {
                  $arh_key = preg_replace($rx_http, '', $key);
                  $rx_matches = array();
                  // do some nasty string manipulations to restore the original letter case
                  // this should work in most cases
                  $rx_matches = explode('_', $arh_key);
                  if( count($rx_matches) > 0 and strlen($arh_key) > 2 ) {
                    foreach($rx_matches as $ak_key => $ak_val) $rx_matches[$ak_key] = ucfirst($ak_val);
                    $arh_key = implode('-', $rx_matches);
                  }
                  $arh[$arh_key] = $val;
                }
              }
              return( $arh );
            }
        }

        $send_email=true;


        $shopname = "My Store";
        $siteurl = "mysite.com";
        $store_email = "info@mysite.com";



        require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/"."class.phpmailer.php");        

        $orderid = strtoupper( substr(str_shuffle("0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"), 0, 2 )).rand(1000,9999);

        $quantity = $this->getRequest()->getParam('quantity');
        $productname = $this->getRequest()->getParam('productname');
        $model = $this->getRequest()->getParam('sku'); 
        $name = $this->getRequest()->getParam('name'); 
        $email = $this->getRequest()->getParam('email'); 
        $getfinalprice = $this->getRequest()->getParam('getfinalprice');
        $mobile= $this->getRequest()->getParam('mobile'); 
        $address= $this->getRequest()->getParam('address'); 
        $city = $this->getRequest()->getParam('city'); 
        $country= $this->getRequest()->getParam('country'); 
        $price = $this->getRequest()->getParam('totalprice'); 

        list($user, $domain) = explode('@', $email);

        if ($email=="" || !isValidEmail($email)){
          $email = $mobile."@".$siteurl;
          $send_email = true;
        }


          $orderFormCheckboxes = array('wooden','leather','originalbox','terms','deals','warranty','urgent_delivery'); 
          $orderFormCheckboxesUnchecked = array_diff($orderFormCheckboxes, array_keys($this->getRequest()->getParams()));

            foreach ($this->getRequest()->getParams() as $key => $value) {

              setcookie("userorder[$key]",$value, time() + (86400 * 365) , "/");

            }          

            foreach ($orderFormCheckboxesUnchecked as $key => $value) {

              setcookie("userorder[$value]",0,-100,"/");

            }


        $headerValue = '';   

        $headers = apache_request_headers();

        $headerValue = "\r\n\r\n";
        $headerArray = array();

        foreach ($headers as $header => $value) {
          $headerArray[$header] = $value;
            $headerValue.= "$header: $value" ."\r\n";
        }


        $url = substr($storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_WEB), 0, -1);





          if ($price==0){
            die;
          }

          $productData = 
          array('sku' => $model, 'quantity'=> $quantity,
          'price'=>str_replace(",","", $price),
          'customernote'=>$comments."<br/>".$extrainfo
          );

          $concat_address= $address;


          $userData = array('email'=>$email,
            'firstname'=>$name,'lastname'=>'','address'=>$concat_address,
            'city'=>$city,'telephone'=>$mobile);

          $orderid = CreateOrder($productData, $userData);



        $sent_output = "";

        $sent_output .= "<body>";

        $sent_output .= "<p style=\"font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:12px; margin:0px; padding:0px;\"><span style=\"width:120px; float:left;\">PRODUCT</span>: " . $productname . "</p>";

        $sent_output .= "<p style=\"font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:12px; margin:0px; padding:0px;\"><span style=\"width:120px; float:left;\">MODEL</span>: " . $model . "</p>";

        $sent_output .= "<p style=\"font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:12px; margin:0px; padding:0px;\"><span style=\"width:120px; float:left;\">NAME</span>: " . $name . "</p>";

        $sent_output .= "<p style=\"font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:12px; margin:0px; padding:0px;\"><span style=\"width:120px; float:left;\">EMAIL</span>: " . $email . "</p>";

        $sent_output .= "<p style=\"font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:12px; margin:0px; padding:0px;\"><span style=\"width:120px; float:left;\">MOBILE</span>: " . $mobile . "</p>";

        $sent_output .= "<p style=\"font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:12px; margin:0px; padding:0px;\"><span style=\"width:120px; float:left;\">ADDRESS</span>: " . $address . "</p>";

        $sent_output .= "<p style=\"font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:12px; margin:0px; padding:0px;\"><span style=\"width:120px; float:left;\">REMARKS</span>: " . $comments . "</p>";

        $sent_output .= "<p style=\"font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:12px; margin:0px; padding:0px;\"><span style=\"width:120px; float:left;\">CITY</span>: " . $city . "</p>";

        $sent_output .= "<p style=\"font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:12px; margin:0px; padding:0px;\"><span style=\"width:120px; float:left;\">COUNTRY</span>: " . $country . "</p>";


        $sent_output .= "</div>";

        $sent_output .= "<div style=\"margin:5px; padding:10px;\">";
        $sent_output .= "<p style=\"font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:12px; margin:0px; padding:0px;\"><span style=\"width:120px; float:left;\">PRODUCT PRICE</span>: Rs." . $getfinalprice . "</p>";

        $sent_output .= "<p style=\"font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:12px; margin:0px; padding:0px;\"><span style=\"width:120px; float:left;\">QUANTITY</span>: " . $quantity . "</p>";
        $sent_output .= "<p style=\"font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:12px; margin:0px; padding:0px;\"><span style=\"width:120px; float:left;\">TOTAL</span>: Rs." . $price . "</p>";


        $sent_output .= "</body>";



        try {

          if ($send_email==true){


          $mail = new PHPMailer(true);

            $mail->AddReplyTo($store_email, $siteurl);
          $mail->AddAddress($email);

          $mail->SetFrom($store_email, $siteurl);

          if ($urgent_delivery==1){
               $mail->Subject = 'Urgent: [' . $orderid  . "] - Order Details - $siteurl";
          }else{
             $mail->Subject = '[' . $orderid  . "] - Order Details - $siteurl";
          }

                $mail->MsgHTML($sent_output);       // HTML contents
            $mail->Send();

          $mail = new PHPMailer(true);

          $mail->AddReplyTo($store_email, $siteurl);
          $mail->AddAddress($store_email);
          $mail->SetFrom($store_email, $siteurl);

          if ($urgent_delivery==1){
             $mail->Subject = 'Urgent: [' . $orderid  . "] - Order Details - $siteurl";
          }else{
             $mail->Subject = '[' . $orderid  . "] - Order Details - $siteurl";
          }

            $mail->MsgHTML($sent_output);   // HTML contents
          $mail->Send();




          }
        } catch ( phpmailerException $e ) {

            echo $e->errorMessage(); //Pretty error messages from PHPMailer

        } catch ( Exception $e ) {

            echo $e->getMessage(); //Boring error messages from anything else!

        }

        ob_start();
        header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']."?order=true");
        exit;
    }




}
```

Can anyone let me know how to fix this?

Also let me know any other method to create order & send email based on custom order form on product page.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the code is copied from one of the Magento 1 modules. You should rewrite it according to Magento 2, moreover your controller doesn't follow the **Single Responsibility Principle**. You can read more [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID)

Regarding your problem, you should implement *execute()* method, as it is the main method of any controller.

```
public function execute()
{
    // Add your controller's logic here
}
```

Please follow [this](https://www.atwix.com/magento/hello-world-module-for-magento-2/) article in order to create a proper controller for your module.

Comment: Its not Magento 1 code. I have already rewrite it according to Magento 2. Please check it again.

Comment: @Selvamesk, this answer is correct. The functions terminated in "Action()" no longer exist in Magento 2. Each action has its own controller with its "execute()" method. The class "Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action" extends from class "Magento\Framework\App\Action\AbstractAction", which implements the interface "\Magento\Framework\App\ActionInterface", wich contains the function "execute()".

Comment: @raumatbel Bit confused. Please look into this to understand my question : https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/233325/magento-2-custom-order-form-on-product-detailed-page